# Reverse proxy not keeping the original domain name

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy

I want to do something like this:

Domain1 = www.abc.com
Domain 2 = www.xyz.com

When someone goes to www.abc.com it should go to www.xyz.com/directory/1

I have this configuration in my apache 2.2 ( yes it has mod_proxy )

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.abc.com
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPass / http://www.xyz.com/directory/1
    ProxyPassReverse / http://www.xyz.com/directory/1
</VirtualHost>
```

The thing is it is working but it shows http://www.xyz.com/directory/1 in the browser location bar, and i want to show abc.com.

I had it working and after i change the domain names from the test to the real one it stoped showing the correct domain, so can someone please tell me if i have something wrong there?

Answer (score 0):

I just figure this out, when i put this:

```
<Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Proxy>
```

It all work as expected :)